# Describe php object

Tags: php

I want to create a function that will do this: check the object and if the property 1 is 001 then print John else if the property 2 is 002 the print Jenny but I dont know how to read the property 1 [001] and describe it as a variable.

The result that I cURL from a file:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [001] => John
            [002] => Jenny
         )
)
```

Comment: It's an object, that's why it says `stdClass Object`.

Comment: If you're using `json_decode()`, give it a second argument `true` to get an array instead of object.

Comment: Actually it's PHP.

Comment: Actually it's John Doe

Comment: I lost you at *"I want to do a function like if the id"*

Comment: The object has two properties in the `id` object. So what do you mean by "if the id is 001"?

Comment: What does this mean: _"check the object and if the property 1 is 001"_? Properties aren't ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the id is present in your object and if it is return the name.  As an example:

```
function get_name_from_id($obj, $id) {
    return $obj->id->$id ?? false;
}
```